# Backbone Marionette routing - only the first route works

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have the following router:

```
define([
    'backbone.marionette',
    'app',
    'views/products/list',
    'views/products/browsing_filter',
    'views/products/detail',
    'views/dashboard/index',
    'views/layout'
],
function(Marionette, App, ProductListView, BrowsingFilterView, ProductDetailView, LayoutView){
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
        routes: {
            'product/:id': 'showProduct',
            'products/:id': 'showProduct',
            'products': 'listProducts',
            '*path': 'showDashboard',
        },

        listProducts: function(path) {
            App.contentRegion.show(new ProductListView());
            product_filter_view = new BrowsingFilterView();
        },

        showProduct: function(id) {
            App.contentRegion.show(new ProductDetailView({id: id}));
        },

        showDashboard: function() {
            return require(['views/dashboard/index', 'collections/newsfeed_items','models/newsfeed_item'], function(DashboardView, NewsfeedItemCollection, NewsfeedItem) {
                App.contentRegion.show(new DashboardView({
                    collection: new NewsfeedItemCollection(),
                    model: new NewsfeedItem()
                }));
            });
        }
    });

    return AppRouter;
});
```

When a route is called it works fine. However, when the next route is called the container for the region `App.contentRegion` is emptied and no new content is rendered.

When the new route is called, the AJAX requests are done as they should, the view simply seems to either become detached or not rendered at all.

What is wrong?

**Edit**:
ProductDetailView:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'backbone',
    'models/product',
    'models/product_property_value',
    'models/product_property',
    'hbs!template/product_detail/detail',
    'hbs!template/product_detail/edit_string',
    'collections/product_property_values',
    'collections/newsfeed_items',
    'hbs!template/newsfeed/feed'
],
function($, Backbone, ProductModel, ProductPropertyValueModel, ProductPropertyModel, ProductDetailTemplate, StringEditTemplate, ProductPropertyValueCollection, NewsfeedItemCollection, FeedTemplate){
    ProductDetailView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#product_detail',
        product_id: null,
        events: {
            'click a.show_edit': 'triggerEdit',
            // 'click div.edit_container a.save': 'saveChanges',
            'submit form.edit_property_value': 'saveChanges',
            'click a.cancel_edit': 'cancelEdit'
        },
        initialize: function(param){
            this.product_id = param.id;

            this.product = new ProductModel({'id': this.product_id});
            this.product.fetch();

            this.newsfeeditems = new NewsfeedItemCollection({'product': {'id': this.product_id}});
            this.listenTo(this.newsfeeditems, 'change', this.renderFeed);
            this.listenTo(this.newsfeeditems, 'fetch', this.renderFeed);
            this.listenTo(this.newsfeeditems, 'sync', this.renderFeed);
            this.newsfeeditems.setProductId(this.product_id);
            this.newsfeeditems.fetch({reset:true});

            this.listenTo(this.product, 'change', this.render);
            this.listenTo(this.product, 'fetch', this.render);
            this.listenTo(this.product, 'sync', this.render);
        },

        renderFeed: function(r) {
            context = this.newsfeeditems.toJSON();
            this.$el.find('#product_newsfeed').html(FeedTemplate({items:context}));
        },

        edit_container: null,
        product_property_model: null,
        triggerEdit: function(r) {
            r.preventDefault();
            this.cancelEdit();
            editable_container = $(r.target).parents('.editable').first();
            product_property_value_ids = editable_container.data('property-value-id');

            edit_container = $(editable_container).find('div.edit_container');
            if(edit_container.length === 0) {
                console.log(edit_container);
                editable_container.append('<div class="edit_container"></div>');
                edit_container = $(editable_container).find('div.edit_container');
            }

            this.edit_container = edit_container;

            value_init = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < product_property_value_ids.length; i++) {
                value_init = {'id': product_property_value_ids[i]};
            }

            if(product_property_value_ids.length > 1) {
                throw new Exception('Not supported');
            }

            this.edit_value = new ProductPropertyValueModel({'id': product_property_value_ids[0]});

            this.listenTo(this.edit_value, 'change', this.renderEditField);
            this.listenTo(this.edit_value, 'reset', this.renderEditField);
            this.listenTo(this.edit_value, 'fetch', this.renderEditField);
            this.edit_value.fetch({'reset': true});

            return false;
        },

        cancelEdit: function() {
            this.$el.find('.edit_container').remove();
        },

        renderEditField: function() {
            edit_container.html(StringEditTemplate(this.edit_value.toJSON()));
        },

        saveChanges: function(r) {
            r.preventDefault();
            console.log('save changes');
            ev = this.edit_value;

            _.each($(r.target).serializeArray(), function(value, key, list) {
                ev.set(value, key);
            });
            ev.save();
        },

        render: function(r) {
            context = this.product.toJSON();
            this.$el.html(ProductDetailTemplate(context));

            $(document).foundation();
            return this;
        }
    });

    return ProductDetailView;
});
```

Comment: Would you be able to put together a basic http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate the problem? From what you've said it sounds like your routing is all set up correctly.

Comment: Is there any deps what route you follow first? anyway, need fiddle

Comment: Can you post your `ProductDetailView` code?

Answer (score 0):

In our app we use `appRoutes` instead of `routes` as the key. I think that is the way you should do it when using Marionette.

Next you should make sure you are starting Backbone.history by using `Backbone.history.start()`.